# AWS subdomain connect to specific folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain, amazon-route53

I want to create a subdomain for specific folder in my server eg: `sub.xxxx.com` and will open what is in `/var/html/sub/` folder

I tried to create subdomain but always gives me this when opening in browser

> server DNS address could not be found

I tried to create from Route 53 and configure the vhost but no success

Comment: Did you do the name server mappings to the hosted zone in route53?

Comment: already tried name server yet it gives the same error when accessing on the browser but when im trying to check it on Test Record Set it gives NoERROR

Answer (score 0):

Go to the amazon Route53 hosted zone you already created for your domain and create record set following below instruction

1. Put the sub domain name into the name field like test.XXXXX.com
2. Select CNAME-canonical name from the type drop down menu
3. Alias (no)
4. TTL- default (300)
5. Value- Just the domain name (XXXXX.com)
6. Routing policy- default (simple)

Comment: Tried but, the subdomain is not propagating. Always says "This site can’t be reached"